# What is the opposite of "coprime integers"?

Tags: terminology, integers, coprime

What do you call two integers that are not relatively prime? In my language, there is a clear term for that, but I can't seem to find one in English.

Comment: "*Integers with a (nontrivial) common factor*"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need a term for it?  Saying "*Let $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(a,b)>1$*" seems clear and concise enough.  Better than using some phrase that people haven't necessarily heard of and needing to define it for them anyways.

Comment: If you want a single word "noncoprime" will work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I'm curious what your language is and what the term is in your language

Comment: Thanks! I need to translate the syllabus of my math class into English and one point is "distinguish between coprime and __________ integers". Would it be fine to use "noncoprime" in this case?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! My language is Czech the term for "coprime" is "nesoudělná" and the opposite is "soudělná".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually, no. You would translate "nesoudelna" as something similar to "non-divisible" (not exactly, but can't think of anything better), meaning that any prime number that divides one does not divide the other

Comment: So the prefix "ne" is a sort of negation? Then "coprime" and "non-coprime" would make sense.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, exactly, "ne" is a negation. However, the numbers that have more common factors are called "soudelna" and then the opposite is "nesoudelna" = "coprime". So you would switch the position of the negation. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I should go to [this school](http://www.matematikasestka.wz.cz/soudelna.html) to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard term for that notion.

"Integers with a nontrivial common factor" is probably the best you can do without symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that!